# code in curly brakets are printing as it is in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have login form that login form has a action `postLogin` of this route.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>route('postLogin'), 'files'=>true)) }
```

This is my route in route.php

```
Route::post("/postLogin","Users@postLogin");

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cookies\CookieServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;    

class Users extends BaseController
{

   public function login()
   {     
       $encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
       $encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());

       return view('users/login');
   }

   public function postLogin()
   {
       print_r($_POST);
       die;
   }
}
```

I have very basic form which has action of
`{{ Form::open(array('url'=>route('postLogin'), 'files'=>true)) }}`

but it is displaying as it is .Whats going wrong in it.

Comment: Does the file have the `.blade.php` extension?

Comment: which file? view file is having .php extension.I have saved this file with test.php

Comment: There's your problem. It should be `test.blade.php`.

Comment: thank you andrew. It works for me.great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should echo it with this brackets  `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`.

`{!! !!}` prints out the html aswell `{{ }}` prints out only the value of a variable.

**note**: The view also should have the extension `.blade.php` so for example `index.blade.php`